# solution to create a user type list in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

It's been a while since I started working on SharePoint online. I found a php library (https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO)that allows me to perform CRUD operations and it works very well. However, I am trying to create a list with many columns including a person type (or user type), but all columns are filled except this one. My question is to know if it is possible to fill a column of type person (except put directly in SharePoint) and if so how?
Thank you

Comment: Hi romaric, i am not sure about the php code. but its pretty much possible to update Person and Group Column Type using Rest API. some of the refrence links here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32245928/inserting-a-user-into-a-person-field-in-sharepoint-using-the-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with php but you could reference the code below to call rest with ajax to fill user field.
Single value user field:

```
var spID =_spPagecontextinfo.userid;//to add current user

strUrl = "http://<site url>//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items";
strheader= {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
};

var itemType = 'SP.Data.ListNameListItem';///ListItemEntityTypeFullName
var item = {
"__metadata": { "type": itemType },
         StakeholderId:spID
};
$.ajax({
url: strUrl,
type: "POST",
async:false,
cache:false,
contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
data: JSON.stringify(item),
headers:strHeader,
success: function (data){
///your code on success
},
error: function (error) {
//return alert(error.responseText);
}
});
```

Multiple value(pass array with user id to StackhoderId property):

```
var item = {
"__metadata": { "type": itemType },
         StakeholderId:{'results':[userid1,userid2]}
};
```